# How do you evaluate $\lim_{x \to 3^+} \frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 3^+} \frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$$

I tried substitution first. (It won't work for this one.) When finding a limit of a fraction and in doubt, rationalize either the numerator or denominator.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: how to calculate Limit[(x - 5 + Sqrt[1 + x])/Sqrt[x^2 - 9], x -> 3]

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site, then edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck.

Comment: rationalize the numerator multiplying by $\frac {x-5 - \sqrt{x+1}}{x-5 - \sqrt{x+1}}$ we should expect to get an $(x-3)$ factor in the numerator.  This will partially cancel with what is in the denominator giving $\sqrt{x-3}(g(x))$ where $g(x)$ is continuous at 3.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you probably should have $\lim_{x\to 3^+}$ ( because if $-3<x <3$, we might be troubled by how to evaluate $\sqrt{x^2-9}$...)

Comment: yes @peter a g i have limx→3+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit does not exist because as you notice we can only find the right limit because the left limit does not make sense at $x=3$.

$$\lim_{x \to 3^+} \frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$$

could be found by multiplying top and bottom by $x-5-\sqrt {x+1}$ where the top factors as $(x-3)(x+8)$ and after elimination of $\sqrt {x-3}$ from the top and bottom we come up with $$\lim_{x \to 3^+} \frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to rationalize the numerator:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\frac{x-5-\sqrt{x+1}}{x-5-\sqrt{x+1}}
&=\frac{x^2-11x+24}{\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+3}\left(x-5-\sqrt{x+1}\right)}\\
&=\frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x-3}}\frac{x-8}{\sqrt{x+3}\left(x-5-\sqrt{x+1}\right)}
\end{align}
$$
Now it is easier to take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=3+h$, $\;h\to 0$. The expression becomes
$$\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\frac{h-2+\sqrt{4+h}}{\sqrt{h(6+h)}}=$$
Now $\;\sqrt{4+h}=2\sqrt{1+\frac h4}=2\bigl(1+\frac  h8+o(h)\bigr)$, so the numerator is
$$h-2+2+\frac h4+o(h)=\frac{5h}4+o(h)\sim_0\frac{5h}4.$$
On the other hand $h(6+h)\sim_06h$, so
$$\frac{h-2+\sqrt{4+h}}{\sqrt{h(6+h)}}\sim_0 \frac{\cfrac{5 h}4}{\sqrt{6h}}=\frac {5\sqrt h}{4\sqrt6}\to 0.$$

Comment: I had the same idea!

Comment: @gimusi: Finally, I thought finding and using equivalents was simpler. That being said, great minds think together ;o)

Comment: I've also modified a little bit without change of variable! But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

By binomial expansion we have

$$\sqrt{x+1}=\sqrt{4+(x-3)}=2\sqrt{1+(x-3)/4}=2+(x-3)/4+o(x-3)$$

and therefore

$$\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\frac{x-5+2+(x-3)/4+o(x-3)}{x^2-9}\sqrt{x^2-9}=$$

$$=\frac{5(x-3)/4+o(x-3)}{x^2-9}\sqrt{x^2-9}=\frac{5/4+o(1)}{x+3}\sqrt{x^2-9}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Well. Let consider the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}
&= \frac{x-3-2+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+3}}
= \frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+3}} + \frac{-2+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+3}} 
\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}} + \frac{\frac{-4+x+1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}}}{\sqrt{x-3}\sqrt{x+3}}
\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}} + \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}}\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{x+3}}\left(1 +  \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{x+1}}\right).
\end{align}
Therefore, by letting $x \to 3$, we have 
$$
\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} = \frac {x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}$

If we can factor out $\sqrt{x -3}$ in the numerator we are good.

$x - 5 + \sqrt {x+1} = x -3 + (-2 + \sqrt{x+1})$ so

$\frac {x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}= \frac {x-3}{\sqrt{x -3}\sqrt{x+3}} + \frac {-2 + \sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x -3}\sqrt{x+3}} = \frac {\sqrt {x-3}}{\sqrt{x + 3}} + \frac {-2 + \sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x -3}\sqrt{x+3}}$

Now we know the first term will go to $0$ and we can rationalize the numerator of the second term via $(-2 + \sqrt{x+1})(-2 - \sqrt{x+1}) = 4 - (x+1) = 3-x$.

So we have:

$\frac {x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{(x-3)(x+3)}}=  \frac {\sqrt {x-3}}{\sqrt{x + 3}} - \frac {x-3}{\sqrt{x -3}\sqrt{x+3}(-2 - \sqrt{x+1})}=  \frac {\sqrt {x-3}}{\sqrt{x + 3}} - \frac {\sqrt{x -3}}{\sqrt{x+3}(-2 - \sqrt{x+1})}$

And $\lim\limits_{x\to 3}\frac{x-5+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 3}\frac {\sqrt {x-3}}{\sqrt{x + 3}} - \frac {\sqrt{x -3}}{\sqrt{x+3}(-2 - \sqrt{x+1})}= \frac 0{\sqrt 6} - \frac 0{-4*\sqrt 6} = 0$

Answer (score 0):

You can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule). It states that
$$
\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to c}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.
$$
In your case $f(x) = x - 5 + \sqrt{x+1}$ and $g(x) =\sqrt{x^2-9}$. Hence
$$
\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to 3}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}\right)\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{x} = 0.
$$

Comment: A student at this level almost surely doesn't know L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Fixed it, thank you!